# How can a JPA 1.0 project be converted to JPA 2.0?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-1.0

We've been using JPA 1.0 for some time now. We want to move ahead to JPA 2.0. How can this be done?

Comment: The person who decided to down-vote this has no idea that it is extremely hard to find at least a mailing list entry on this. Migration is a very common occurrance and migration between two standards, the latter being an upgrade of the former, is very common. I believe a reason to down-vote should've been given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed the version name and xsd as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
```

Which worked fine.

Please mention in comments if you think additional things need to be done and I will update this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could do worse than to [read the migration guide from OpenJPA](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.jpafep.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Frejb_jpa2mig.html) and then ask a more specific question.

Comment: @RavindranathAkila evidently not useful enough to be accepted though?

Comment: I do prefer a more vendor independent link :-)

Comment: Then feel free to provide one :p

Comment: :D ok ok, will look for one! :D

Comment: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.0.0/apache-openjpa/docs/migration_considerations.html#jpa_2.0 ;-)

Comment: ... and how exactly is OpenJPA **not** vendor independant?

Comment: Actually, I couldn't find a proper link either. I feel my answer is adequate if one actually coded fully compliant to JPA 1.0. Just changing the persistence.xml entry would work, IMO. It worked in our case.

Comment: I read through the document, and most of the configuration required were OpenJPA specific. Vendor dependent correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20038/discussion-between-ravindranath-akila-and-hd1)

Comment: You said you "do prefer a more vendor independent link" and proceeded to provide one from apache's openjpa project. This seems to be more bickering, so I'll stop now

Comment: You asked for a better link, and I found the original source of the link you provided, openjpa docs itself, and is more readable.